# Getting react-native-gesture-handler module was not found error for react-native-run-ios command

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

I have updgraded my React Native version to 0.70.3 from 0.64.2 and accordingly upgraded the packages.

When running the debugging(react-native run-ios) for IOS, the above error is occurring on react-native-gesture-handler. If you have any method to fix this or any advice please share with me.

Added all the details(code,screenshots,errors) to check in-detailed,Thanks in advance.

Please help me in reolving the issue by sharing the sample code or steps for resolving.

Below are the list of packages used in the project,

```
{
  "name": "projectSetup",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^9.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.5",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.3",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1275.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.1",
    "react-native-flexbox-grid": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.0",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-month-selector": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.12",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-sound-player": "^0.13.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

App.js file below code

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, LogBox, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // LogBox.ignoreAllLogs()
        return (
            <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex:1}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'#000',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'#fff'}}>Welcome to Home !!</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**ERROR  [react-native-gesture-handler] react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..).

For installation instructions, please refer to https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation**

[image]

[image]

at TouchableOpacity onPress **getting the error as cannot read property handlesetjsresponder of null**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have install the package but you need to install the Pods for ios.

So just do

1. cd ios
2. pod install
3. cd ..

Then rerun the app again following the command react-native-run-ios

Comment: Tried the above steps also, still not working

Comment: Maybe because of "react-native": "^0.70.3", the gesture issue

Comment: npm uninstall react-native-gesture-handler --save

npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save

Try again

Comment: Now tried unistalling and installing the package, still the same error.